# Problems while drawing views on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview

I am creating a footer of recyclerview using itemdecorators. The code works fine when I pass a `textview` as a footerView. But the problem is that the gravity of my view is botched up. Please also note that I asked for view as an argument as I wanted to make a generic footer. How can I correct the problem.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;



public class FooterDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
  private View mLayout;

  public FooterDecorator(final Context context, @LayoutRes int resId) {
    mLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId, null, false);
    mLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
  }

  public FooterDecorator(View view) {
    mLayout = view;
    mLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

    mLayout.layout(parent.getLeft(), 0, parent.getRight(), mLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
      View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
      if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
        c.save();
        c.translate(0, view.getBottom());
        mLayout.draw(c);
        c.restore();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
      outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
My layout resource file-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_all_flights"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Please also note that my click listeners to the view aren't working as well.

Comment: simply add a footer view to your adapter, and not draw it inside `ItemDecoration`

Comment: I know that is a solution. But if I do that I will have to modify the adapters and there are about 10 such adapters. I want a solution where I won't have to modify all these adapters. This is why I decided to go for ItemDecoration.

Comment: you have to call `measure()` with `widthMeasureSpec` like this: `View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredFinalWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)`

Comment: I did this also, but still the same result.

Comment: post the layout file you are passing to `FooterDecorator(final Context context, @LayoutRes int resId)`

Comment: try http://pastebin.com/yCAKeQGH

Comment: @pskink The code is more or less the same. Anyways, I solved the gravity problem by encapsulating the view by a linearlayout. But, I am still not getting the click listener to work.

Comment: this code solves gravity issues, no need for any linearlayout, and no, no click listeners will work that way

Comment: @pskink I am not getting a call on the click listeners. I put logs and breakpoints but it won't go there.

Comment: as i said: you will not get any callbacks: your view is not added to any parent view - it is just drawn, nothing else

Comment: So should I pass parent while inflating?

Comment: see my first comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980402/problems-while-drawing-views-on-canvas#comment71139964_41980402): simply add a footer view to your adapter, and not draw it inside `ItemDecoration`

Comment: @pskink looks like I will have to go with that approach only. Thanks for your help though.